# How to set seed in python

Tags: python, random-seed

I want to draw the same exact samples from the data, two times, in order to run a different analysis each time. To do so I did

```
random.seed(10)
data.sample(n = 1000)
```

But this is not working, I get different samples each time. I searched for a built-in parameter in the `sample()` function but I found non. How do I set seed?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just copy the first one?

Comment: Make a [mcve] where this doesn't work.  What is `data`?  `random.seed(10]; random.sample([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k=3)` returns the same values each time.

Comment: Mark's solution works just fine when I run from a file. In the interpreter I had to declare seed every time before I sample it to make it work.

Comment: @Supertech You normally have to re-seed to get the same "random" sequence.

Comment: I guess you should use `random.sample(data, 1000)`.